# How to change url by action filter and still redirect to executing route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

**Aim:** I have a url like `http://localhost:55830/shop/116_news` - among other things, the filter has the task to change url to `http://localhost:55830/shop/news`

I tried:

```
filterContext.RouteData.Values[ActionFilter.Value] = "/shop/" + StringHelper.RemoveDiacritics(value.Value.ToLower());
filterContext.ActionArguments[ActionFilter.Value] = "/shop/" + StringHelper.RemoveDiacritics(value.Value.ToLower());
filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path = "/shop/" + StringHelper.RemoveDiacritics(value.Value.ToLower());
```

None of above change url during `OnActionExecuting`

Whole action filter class:

```
public class ValueUrlFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
        private readonly IValueTypeRepository repositoryValueType;

        public ValueUrlFilterAttribute(IValueTypeRepository repoValueType)
        {
            repositoryValueType = repoValueType;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            string v = filterContext.RouteData.Values[ActionFilter.Value] as string;

            List<string> vInfo = ActionFilter.GetList(v);
            int valueId = ActionFilter.GetValueId(vInfo);
            string valueName = ActionFilter.GetValueName(vInfo);

            ValueType value = repositoryValueType.GetValueByValueId(valueId);

            if (value.Value.ToLower() == valueName)
            {
                object param;

                filterContext.RouteData.Values[ActionFilter.Value] = "/shop/" + StringHelper.RemoveDiacritics(value.Value.ToLower());
                filterContext.ActionArguments[ActionFilter.Value] = "/shop/" + StringHelper.RemoveDiacritics(value.Value.ToLower());
                filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path = "/shop/" + StringHelper.RemoveDiacritics(value.Value.ToLower());

                if (filterContext.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("value", out param))
                {
                    filterContext.ActionArguments["value"] = value;
                }

                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }
        }
}
```

I don't want to redirect to another action, I want to go to the action that I originally called

**PS** Sending new argument `filterContext.ActionArguments["value"] = value;` works great!

**Issue** I don't know how to change `http://localhost:55830/shop/116_news` to `http://localhost:55830/shop/news`

Thanks!

Comment: what is the issue ? is it already solved ?

Comment: I dont know how to change -> `http://localhost:55830/shop/116_news` to `http://localhost:55830/shop/news`

Comment: Is there any specific reason you use `ActionFilterAttribute`? It seems you want to rewrite the request url, if so, you may try [URL Rewriting Middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the RouteAttribute con your action method:

```
[Route("shop/news")]
public IActionResult AnythingHere()
{
   return View();
}
```

If you need to remove 116 from multiple urls consider makeing a global template in Startup.cs more info here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1

If you want to change the URL in the browser then it's not possible without a redirect.

Comment: for testing I made archon like this:
`<a asp-controller="@v.Controller" asp-action="@RouteUrl.Index" asp-route-value="@v.Value.ToLower()" asp-route-valueId="@v.ValueId" class="nav-link" >@v.Value</a>`

Now I have problem with regex:
`AddRewrite(
    @"^shop/(.*)?valueId=(\d+)",
    "shop/$1", 
    true
);`

Comment: .AddRedirect(@"shop/116_news(.*)", "shop/news$1") ? @szkut

Comment: I think this is correct answer, but I have problem with `AddRedirect` I will create a new topic for that

Comment: In my situation in the end of my problem - action filter, and rewriting dosen't helped me. I think in difrent scenario rewriting is very helpful and can replace the action filter which does redirect. Thats why I will leave this answer as acepted.

Here the link what i did to achive my aim:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52564527/9169938), -

below text copied from question "Aim: I have a url like http://localhost:55830/shop/116_news - among other things, the filter has the task to change url to http://localhost:55830/shop/news"