# Asp.net Middleware ReWrite is not forwarding request to intended url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm simply trying to route all incoming request to a particular page via the ReWrite middleware, but I am not getting the desired result. In fact, the website behaves as if the middleware isn't even in the pipeline. I have placed the logic in the startup file right before app.UseEndpoints.

```
var isMaintenance = true;

if (isMaintenance)
{
    var options = new RewriteOptions()
          .AddRewrite(@"^(.*)", "/maintenance", true);
    app.UseRewriter(options);
}

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

Comment: Take a look this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52472923/url-rewriting-middleware-asp-net-core-2-0

Comment: @So_oP yes I've seen that post already, and still can't figure it out. Maybe I'm missing something. The app this is for is a Blazor Server-side app. Not sure if this changes anything, but i my regex wrong or is it something else.  Again, I'm just simply trying to intercept all request and rewrite them to the /maintenance page.

Comment: Rewriter is hard to work,why not use redirect？