# Dotnet core application does not consistently catch exceptions

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, .net-core

I will try my best to explain the exception I am facing. I have an application built with dotnet core 2.1 running under localhost:5000. I have applied the global exception handler within the startup class to handle any exception thrown by the application. I have tested this functionality and its working absolutely fine. However, if I pass this 'http://localhost:5000/redirect=https%3a%2f%2fey.com' in the url it throws an exception but doesn't get caught within the application. Please refer to the screenshot attached. My requirement is to redirect the user to a generic error page.

[EDITED] This issue was found during QA testing. Also, 'redirect' is not a keyword here, if we try to replace redirect with any random character throws the same exception. eg 'http://localhost:5000/a=https%3a%2f%2fey.com'

[image]

Comment: you could use use asp.net core middleware for rewriting URLS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Show your `Startup.cs`

Comment: @mtkachenko here is an excerpt from the startup class.

Comment: var options = new RewriteOptions()
                    .AddRedirectToHttps();
                app.UseRewriter(options);
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Client/Home/Error");

Comment: @ArvindMaurya I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: because of whitespaces in URL, you are getting an exception to redirect ,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.1#regex-examples-1 you can use pattern matching  and try

Comment: @ArvindMaurya even without the whitespaces I am getting this error. I somehow need to show a error page like 404 or something.

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52473583/804385 shows you the options you have to configure redirect rules (note `app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(new RedirectWwwRule()));`) - you can handle all you want in your custom rule like `RedirectWwwRule` in the example provided by @siavash